# In a dynamo, how does current have enough time to flow through the wire if, in no time, it changes direction?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current

I had a lot of problems imaging the current in an AC generator.

I fully understand the principal of it and how it depends on a magnetic field repeatedly cutting another one and how to use Fleming's right hand rule, I only still have trouble imagining why emf changes when the wire is in different positions.

Anyway it's easy to imagine current changing direction when we are working with a single wire.
[image]

But in a dynamo it's a rectangular coil/wire, and as it rotates **at the same time** the wire to the left will be cutting ,say, downwards the wire to the right will be cutting upwards.

So the way I wound up imagining it is sth like this: in a cross section of a wire electrons will be forced to flow in one direction then **at the same time** before they even flow away from the rectangular coil and to the rest of the wire to, let's say, a lamp they will be pushed back to the opposite direction.

Comment: The electrons don't "flow away from the coil and to the rest of the wire". Each electron only oscillates back and forth by a fraction of a millimeter in each revolution of the dynamo. But since the wire is "full" of electrons, if the ones in the coil move a fraction of a millimeter, they "push" the electrons outside the coil the same amount and the ones inside the lamp heat up the filament to light up the lamp as they move.

Comment: So contrary to the DC current, the electrons won't move a lot of distance since they will always go back  to the few atoms they left behind then they will go forward the same distance and so on, right?

Comment: even in DC the electrons move not "a lot of distance", just fraction of a mm per second but all in the same direction all the time. If you switch on your batterie driven penlight the electron from th positive side will reach the positiv side only after  many minutes.

Answer (score 0):

In an AC generator, the two sides of a “loop” are part of a circuit.  If you consider the two sides being connected together at one end, and connected by a resistor (perhaps at some distance) at the other end, then both side are pushing electrons the same direction around the circuit (and then the direction reverses when the loop flips over).  Those making comments have noted that the electrons do not move very far.